# How to host a Vue App with a PHP back-end

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a web app running with VueJS as the front-end and PHP as the back-end.

I've been searching for hours but still can't figure out how to host that.

I currently have hosted the front-end on Heroku, and I'm now wondering if there is a way to store any php back-end with a database on Heroku.

My Git repo :

[image]

All my js files are in the src/ folder,
and in the api/ folder I have all the back-end (api endpoints, php classes, db connection etc..)

What url should I write for my API calls?
[image]

Do you know other platforms that would be a fit?

Thanks

Comment: What is it thats blocking the you? Php is fairly standard for a web host provider I'd have thought, and vue is a client side so it's just in the browser and shouldn't be affected by the holster particularly, should it? (I re-wrote this about 5 times as it reads like I'm having a go, I'm not - just probing for some more information about what exactly is causing a problem)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! I edited my question so you can see the structure of the project. I think right now I'm having a hard time setting up the db with heroku. I thought I needed 1 place to host my vue files, and another to host the back-end, but it looks like I can do all that in 1 place do you agree?? thanks!

Comment: _"What url should I write for my API calls?"_ - That 100% depends on how you set it up. There are many ways and if you do some [proper research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) you'll find there's a lot of good articles/guides out there. This is a common way of building apps today so it's far from a unique setup. Also, asking for recommendations/suggestions for things like hosting is unfortunately off-topic here.

Comment: As for 'do[I] agree - it's really down to choice.  If you have separated out your front end from your api and your database you can potentially host each of them in different places.  There are seemingly endless possible choices and you just need to pick an architectural style and go with it.  Micro services are the trend at the moment and are something I perso ally enjoy, but it depends on the project.  If you are hitting apis from a front end then there is no requirement to host the in the same place